# what html framework is used for tensorflow.org

Tags: html, css

I wonder what framework is used for the tensorflow

I like the multilevel menu that they have

any idea what html framework are they using?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow is owned by Google, and I believe that they would use an internal framework for this.
You can use public open source frameworks. I myself, have been playing with Materialize (http://materializecss.com/). I have found this to be quite simple and effective. Specifically for this menu, you can use the Drag Out Menu, as demonstrated here: http://materializecss.com/mobile.html. This makes use of th jQuery SideNav plugin.

As for whether you can make it a multi level menu easily, I cannot answer that question. However, I would suggest that this could be achieved within the HTML Markup and likely also via CSS.

Comment: Thanks, It's very interesting framework. for sure i will look into it